# How to implement CSP in Sveltekit using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, sveltekit, content-security-policy

I'm using Sveltekit 2.4.1 and Firebase 10.7.2

I keep getting these errors:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://*.firebaseapp.com https://apis.google.com 'nonce-zaZNxL4zo3NvTpFUxjH34Q=='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-cE+QbSGwnArC663xa8uRYUjID4yrwUm6Dd3uaAgly0s='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

This is my CSP config:

```
csp: {
            mode: 'auto',
            directives: {
              "base-uri": ["'self'"],
              "default-src": ["'self'"],
              "script-src": [
                "'self'",
                "https://*.firebaseapp.com",
                "https://apis.google.com",
                // Add nonce placeholder if SvelteKit is managing nonces
              ],
              "connect-src": ["'self'", "https://*.firebaseio.com", "wss://*.firebaseio.com"],
              "img-src": ["'self'", "data:"],
              "style-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
              "frame-src": ["https://*.firebaseapp.com"], // Allow framing from Firebase
            }
          }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the code link in the error message to see the code that got blocked by the policy. Likely reasons are

- The element is not nonceable. Only script and style tags can have nonces. Script/style attributes and inline event handlers can't be handled with nonces. You'll need to rewrite them to not use attributes (work with classnames for styles and event listeners for inline event handlers instead).
- The nonce isn't matching.
- Third party code that can't pass the nonce is injecting a script (inline or attribute).

Comment: That was it, it was an inline script that an import was injecting to the html. Thank you